# How to specify a dynamic root URL in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, web-applications, url-routing

Ember allows for a root URL to be specified on the router here: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/#toc_specifying-a-root-url

```
App.Router.reopen({
  rootURL: '/blog/'
});
```

Is there a way to specify a dynamic URL like: `/:region/:locale/`?

The `rootURL` assignment seems to only accept a literal string.

Assets (including Ember) are being loaded from a common directory like `/assets/`.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the workflow a bit of how you would expect it to behave?

Answer (score 7):

You can set `rootURL` dynamically within `Router.init` method, e.g.

```
App.Router.reopen({
  init: function() {
     // set rootURL using regex to extract appropriate
     // rootURL based on current window location
     this.set('rootURL', 
       window.location.pathname.match('/[^/\]*/[^/\]*/')[0]);
     this._super();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to declare you're root URL '/', and then create the rest as routes/resources under that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this within an instance-initializer - I set the root url as a meta environment variable using ember-cli-meta-options, then applied it to the router

```
export default {
  name: "router",

  initialize: function( instance ) {

    var router = instance.container.lookup('router:main');
    var options = instance.container.lookup('session:env');
    router.rootURL = options['root'];

  }
};
```