# Internationalization of ember application

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using `ember-i18n` lib for Internationalisation and want to save current locale in route like:

`domain.com` - empty for default `en`

`doman.com/es`, `doman.com/de`- for another

For this I tried to use `rootURL`

```
Router.reopen({
  rootURL: '/' ('es' or 'de')
});
```

**Problem**: When `rootURL` is not empty, app can't redirect and fail with error: `ember.debug.js:4903 Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Path / does not start with the provided rootURL /es/`

**Question**: What is the best solution to make redirect, all logic will be hold in emebr so I can't move this logic into nginx and etc.

Another option is Make a wrapper route, looks like this:

```
this.route(
    'lang', { path: '/:lang' }, function (){..}
);
```

This solution looks like not good:

1. `link-to` helper will require `lang` param
2. `lang` can't be empty (for default language)

**UPDATE**: I understand how to dynamic change rootURL, but can't auto redirect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify a dynamic root URL in Ember.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957895/how-to-specify-a-dynamic-root-url-in-ember-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, describe this logic in instance-initializer

```
    export function initialize(app) {
  var router = app.lookup('router:main');
  var i18n = app.lookup('service:i18n');

  var path = window.location.pathname;
  var currentLang = ENV.i18n.defaultLocale;
  var newPath = '';

  var LangFromPath = path.match('^/([a-z]{2})(?:/|$)');
  if (LangFromPath && LangFromPath[1]){
    currentLang = (ENV.i18n.allowedLocales.indexOf(LangFromPath[1]) > -1) ? LangFromPath[1] : currentLang;
  }

  if (currentLang != ENV.i18n.defaultLocale) {
    var newPath = '/' + currentLang + '/';
  }

  router.rootURL = newPath;
  i18n.set('locale', currentLang);

  if (newPath && path.indexOf(newPath) === -1) {
      window.location.pathname = newPath;
  }

}
```